# Existence for $-\Delta u + (g(x)-\Delta u)^+\varphi(u) = f(x)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be a smooth bounded domain. Consider the equation 
$$-\Delta u + (g(x)-\Delta u)^+\varphi(u) = f(x)$$
$$u|_{\partial\Omega} = 0$$
where $f,g$ are smooth functions on $\Omega$ and $\varphi$ is a real valued map which is such that $0 \leq \varphi \leq M$ for some constant $M$.

How do I show existence for this equation?

My problem here is the positive-part term there. I tried to apply a Tikhonov fixed point approach in the spaces $H^2$ to the PDE
$$-\Delta u + (g(x)-\Delta w)^+\varphi(u) = f(x)$$
but this requires some weak continuity: if $w_n \rightharpoonup w$ in $H^2$, I would have to show that the corresponding solutions $u_n \to u$ in some space, where $u$ solves the limit problem. But I cannot say anything about the weak convergence of the $(\cdot)^+$ term.

Any existence in Holder or Sobolev spaces would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Is $\varphi$ at least continuous?

Comment: @fedja Yes, it is a smooth function.

Comment: This is just a partial answer, let me come back to this problem in a short while.

I assume that $f$ is non-negative. First of all, remark that from the strong maximum principle we have $u > 0$ on $\Omega$. Conversely, if $v$ denotes the solution to
\begin{eqnarray}
-\Delta v &=& f(x)~\text{on } \Omega\\
v &=& 0~\text{on } \partial\Omega,
\end{eqnarray}
we have $u \leq v$ once again from the maximum principle.

Comment: @romaingicquaud thanks for your attention but how does that help?

Comment: Just some comments: Set $w=v-u$ (with $v$ as in @RomainGicquaud). Then applying the maximum principle to $w$ you can see that if $f+g \leq 0$ then $u=v$ which gives you existence at least in a special case (though it's trivial). So at least you can assume $f(x)+g(x)>0$ for some $x$.

Comment: @C_Al: the usual strategy in such a context is to construct barriers (aka sub and super-solutions) and try to set up an iteration method. Yet, it is not clear whether a maximum principle holds for this equation. I was unable to go further.